# How to reconnect/extend edge loop

Tags: edges

So I made an edge loop on horizontal along size the whole side of this object as you can see in the front, and where it is in red that is me extruding the selected face. However, I messed up and had to delete bunch of geometry and then re-add it (that very long rect on right side is what I redid). So then I wanted to basically re-do the edge loops I made and extend them to this re-done geometry.

So I went and started to dissolve edges on the faces, but did not realize that the edge loop was still there, and was wondering why I couldn't re-add edge loop, until I extruded this face and saw that I only dissolved the visible side.

So my question here is, either A) How do I easily recombine my geometry (even the not so visible sides) or B) how to I "extend" the edge loop to these faces I dissolved them on.

[image: **airplane tutorial**]

Comment: So you want to re do edge loops on the right (square part) but not on the left (vertical rectangles)?

Answer (score 1):

That picture has only face selection mode right?

Because I can see a whole bunch of zero area faces that are going to be confusing.

First thing you should do is try to get rid of those faces by selecting everything and merging vertices by distance (use a very small distance).

Once the faces are cleaned up you should be able to easily cut the edge loops you want either with the knife tool or by dissolving and re-adding with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd>.

Comment: ditto, it looks like some of your edges are concealing collapsed faces. You need to merge vertices to get rid of those, then selecting edge rings/loops might work again. However, that might also depend on how dramatic your dihedral angle patterns are (the pattern of angles between adjacent face normals)